# Determining a Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Consider the non-homogeneous wave equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} &= c^2 u_{xx}+Q(x,t),~~x > 0, \\
u(x,0)&=f(x), \\ 
u_t(x,0)&=g(x), \\
u(0,t)&=h(t).
\end{cases}
$$

The question is to determine the appropriate Green's function. Nothing specific about the function $Q(x,t)$ is given. The second part of the problem is to solve for $u(x,t)$ for certain values of $Q,f$ and $g.$ Any help in getting this done is much appreciated.

Comment: For solving the problem try [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel's_principle#Wave_equation). I'm not familiar with the notion of Green's function in this setting, so I can't say more.